# My minecraft is not launching

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I started playing Minecraft recently .I am using the Java version running on a Windows 10 PC. When I installed it and entered the play demo, it showed as it is in the *image*. What do I do now? I have reinstalled it but didn't work either.

Comment: Have you installed Java on your computer? If not, go to https://www.java.com/en/download/

Answer (score 2):

It literally says "java.exe does not exist on Path="D:\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\bin".

Go to your launcher settings, click on tab "Installations" then select the profile that you're using & pick option "Edit". Click "MORE OPTIONS" then look for "Java executable" and select "Browse"--

*opt. A:* switch to "runtime" folder and delete "jre-x64" ("jre-x32"), then restart MC launcher.

*opt. B:* search for "javaw.exe", click "Open" and restart your launcher.
note: "java.exe" and "javaw.exe" are the same app (except for console execution that doesn't really affect anything).

**Make sure you have the latest version of java on your computer**